# I need help reading data from all files in a directory

Tags: java, file, io

I have a piece of code that iterates over all the files in a directory.
But I am stuck now at reading the content of the file into a String object.

```
public String filemethod(){
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            files = path.list();
            String[] ss;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                ss = files[i].split("\\.");
                if (files[i].endsWith("txt"))
                    System.out.println(files[i]);
            }
        }

    return String.valueOf(files);
}
```

Comment: What then after reading the content of files ? what do you want to do ?

Comment: I have many files in a dir that contains words that could help me in check spelling. Now I'm trying to read all data from these files.

Comment: Use Spring integration for reading multiple files. Also you can read it in parallel, which will help you in performance as well. 

You can split the content to different targets after you read the files using Spring integration.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with a similar problem and wrote a code a while back. This will read the content of all files of a directory.

May require adjustments based on your file directories but its tried and tested code.Hope this helps :)

```
package FileHandling;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BufferedInputStreamExample {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    public void readFile(File folder) {
        ArrayList<File> myFiles = listFilesForFolder(folder);

        for (File f : myFiles) {
            String path = f.getAbsolutePath();

            //Path of the file(Optional-You can know which file's content is being printed)
            System.out.println(path);
            File infile = new File(path);

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                while (dis.available() != 0) {
                    String line = dis.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                    bis.close();
                    dis.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<File> listFilesForFolder(final File folder){
        ArrayList<File> myFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                myFiles.addAll(listFilesForFolder(fileEntry));
            } else {
                myFiles.add(fileEntry);
            }
        }
        return myFiles;
    }
}
```

Main method

```
package FileHandling;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //Your directory here
    final File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\IB\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaIO\\files");

    BufferedInputStreamExample bse = new BufferedInputStreamExample();
    bse.readFile(folder);

    }
}
```

Comment: Inside your `listFilesForFolder` method, you should catch the returned list of `listFilesForFolder()` in case it is a directory. Otherwhise you should drop the line, if you're not interested of the content of the subdirs.

Comment: Adjusted the answer based on the comment as per the best of my knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use following code:

```
public static Collection<File> allFilesInDirectory(File root) {
    Set<File> retval = new HashSet<>();
    Stack<File> todo = new Stack<>();
    todo.push(root);
    while (!todo.isEmpty()) {
        File tmp = todo.pop();
        if (tmp.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : tmp.listFiles())
                todo.push(child);
        } else {
            if (isRelevantFile(tmp))
                retval.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

All you need then is a method that defines what files are relevant for your usecase (for instance txt)

```
public static boolean isRelevantFile(File tmp) {
    // get the extension
    String ext = tmp.getName().contains(".") ? tmp.getName().substring(tmp.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1) : "";
    return ext.equalsIgnoreCase("txt");
}
```

Once you have all the files, you can easily get all the text with a little hack in Scanner

```
public static String allText(File f){
    // \\z is a virtual delimiter that marks end of file/string
    return new Scanner(f).useDelimiter("\\z").next();
}
```

So now, using these methods you can easily extract all the text from an entire directory.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    File rootDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    String tmp = "";
    for(File f : allFilesInDirectory(rootDir)){
         tmp += allText(f);
    }
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class ReadDataFromFiles {
    static final File DIRECTORY = new File("C:\\myDirectory");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //append content of each file to sb
        for(File f : getTextFiles(DIRECTORY)){
            sb.append(readFile(f)).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
    // get all txt files from the directory
    static File[] getTextFiles(File dir){
        FilenameFilter textFilter = (File f, String name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        return dir.listFiles(textFilter);
    }
    // read the content of a file to string
    static String readFile(File file) throws IOException{
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```